# Click event inside dynamically added table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm adding a table dynamically to `JQuery MObile UK`

Table goes on like this

```
<table><TR><TD><a href="#" id="ClickedMe"></a><TD></TR></table>
```

Table then apended in to he HTML

Later I try to bind a click event like this

```
$('#ClickedMe').bind('click', function(e){
    alert("hello");
});
```

But the alert never gets triggered.

====update===

this is how the table dynamically apended into a string

```
cust = cust + "<table id='cusTable'><tr><td scope='row'>" + getLocalizeLbl("phone") + ":</td><td>" + c.PhoneNo + "</td>";
    cust = cust + "</tr><tr><td scope='row'>" +  getLocalizeLbl("fax") + ":</td><td>" + c.Fax + "</td>";
    cust = cust + "</tr><tr><td rowspan='1'></td></tr><tr><td scope='row'>" +  getLocalizeLbl("contact") + ":</td><td><a href='contacts.html' rel='external'>" + dc.Name + "</a></td>";
    sessionStorage.ContactID=dc.ID;
    cust = cust + "</tr><tr><td scope='row'>" +  getLocalizeLbl("email") + ":</td><td>" + dc.Email + "</td>";
    cust = cust + "</tr><tr><td scope='row'>" +  getLocalizeLbl("direct") + ":</td><td>" + dc.Direct + "</td>";
    cust = cust + "</tr><tr><td scope='row'>" +  getLocalizeLbl("mobile") + ":</td><td>"+ dc.Mobile + "</td></tr>";
    cust = cust + "</tr><tr><td scope='row'>" +  'Bill to Cust' + ":</td><td><a href='#' id='ClickedMe'>333343</a></td></tr></table>"
```

and I try to place the function as given in the all answers inside the pagecreate event but still no luck. Why this alert is not getting triggered??

Comment: New to jquery? using latest version? http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Otherwise, check out .live or .delegate

Comment: do you use .live() when you append the table? http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: It's rude to say it, but watch out, You got here a lot of **wrong answers!** be careful...

Comment: but none of the answers worked for me :( :( I updated the question

Comment: How do you add the table? And please show the rendered HTML as well and full script code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you're after is:

```
$('#containerId').on('click', '#ClickMe',function(e){
  alert("hello");
});
```

**But that doesn't make sense.** The selector is for `id` and id must be **unique**!. So when you add the new `#ClickMe` element attach it the click callback.

```
$('#ClickMe').click(function(e){
    alert("hello");
});
```

Read the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (Though it's couple of paragraphs to read...):

> If selector is omitted or is null, the event handler is referred to as
>   direct or directly-bound. The handler is called every time an event
>   occurs on the selected elements, whether it occurs directly on the
>   element or bubbles from a descendant (inner) element.
>
> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as
>   delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on
>   the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that
>   match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up
>   to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to
>   outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that
>   path matching the selector.
>
> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event
>   handler, as described next.
>
> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This
>   element could be the container element of a view in a
>   Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event
>   handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The
>   document element is available in the head of the document before
>   loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without
>   waiting for the document to be ready.

Comment: Actually ClickMe element is unique. It comes only once in he table. I try to bind it to click event but still its not working

Answer (score 1):

Change your calls from `.bind()` to `.on()` - Check the API reference [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/) since it will need a slight 'signature' change.

Bind only works for elements that are in the DOM at the current time (i.e. nothing injected into the DOM will have the event bound)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.on` , bind events for dynamic content:

```
$(document).on("click", "#ClickedMe", function(){ alert("hello"); });
```

---

*Don't use `.live`, it's deprecated : http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: `live()` has been deprecated. Use `on()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is no text inside the , so it can't be clicked. Add some content in there to be able to click it.

Alternately, add the id to the table, tr, or td to make that clickable instead.

Additionally, you should probably use `.live` instead of `.bind`.

Comment: Wow so many people recommending usage of `live`. live is **deprecated** and there're new functions instead(`delegate` and `on`) since **version 1.4.4**

Answer (score 0):

According to api.jquery.com, the .live() method is deprecated. It will probably do the trick but better to do something like this:

```
$("#ClickedMe").on("click", function(event){
    alert("hello");
});
```

Comment: That won't work. you omitted the selector. Read my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9721033/601179)

Comment: @gdoron the selector is optional. I copied this code from api.jquery.com and tested it and it works. However, Jim is correct that it helps to have something inside the anchor tag to click.

Comment: Please read the docs I added to my answer. (You're wrong if you omit the selector, it won't catch dynamically added elements!) _"If selector is omitted or is null, the event handler is referred to as direct or directly-bound. The handler is called every time an event occurs on the selected elements, whether it occurs directly on the element or bubbles from a descendant (inner) element."_

Comment: @gdoron Yes, you are right. But that quote doesn't really help explain why. Seems to me that calling `$("#ClickedMe").on()` will have no effect simply because an element with an ID of "ClickedMe" doesn't exist yet. But if I call it on a container that does exist in the DOM now then I can pass a selector for elements that it will recognize after they are added.

Comment: Correct, so this explains my answer... `$('#containerId').on('click', '#ClickMe',function(e){
  alert("hello");
});` Notice that I attached the callback to the container. .good luck mate! =)

Answer (score 0):

This is simple example how dynamicly get element from DOM and do some operation on it.

```
$(val).on("change", function (e) {
        var valnew = e.currentTarget.value;
        console.log(valnew);
        var name = e.currentTarget.parentNode;
        var name2 = name.nextElementSibling;
        var name3 = name2.childNodes;
        name3[1].innerHTML = valnew;
        console.log(name2);

    });
```

Object val this is element which I pass across method onclick inside HTML code:

```
<input type="range"  onmousedown="SetRangeVal(@rabat.id_usluga,this)" onma value="0" maxlength="100" step="1" />
```

First code I put inside anonymous function :

```
var SetRangeVal = function(id,val){

};
```

Everythings works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery `on()` to accomplish this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#ClickedMe', function(e){
  alert("hello");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

This will work on elements dynamically inserted into the DOM.

Comment: _"This will work on elements dynamically inserted into the DOM."_ **Not without a selector!**

Comment: That won't work. you omitted the selector. Read my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9721033/601179)

Comment: Dude, Your answer was wrong(just like most of the answer to this question), why are you complaining?

Comment: (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻ I know it is! Aggghh! :)